# List all processes I can kill, so I can kill them

Tags: kill, ps, posix

I need to figure out all the processes I can kill as my user (without privileges), so I can kill them. how do I do that? I just wanna kill everything I can.

Comment: What is the operating system you are running?

Comment: I'd like to do it in the most posix compliant way.

Comment: That's helpful information. Please add it to the question. The command options may vary between OS. It would help if you can mention all the OS that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [kill()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall accepts the PID `-1` to specify "all possible processes".

> If *pid* equals -1, then *sig* is sent to every process for which the calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1 (*init*), but see below.
>
> [...]
>
> POSIX.1 requires that kill(-1,*sig*) send sig to all processes that the calling process may send signals to, except possibly for some implementation-defined system processes.

From command line, use `kill -TERM -1`. (The signal name must be explicitly specified, otherwise the "-1" will be misinterpreted as specifying SIGHUP rather than specifying the process ID).

---

To *enumerate* all killable processes:

1. Find out your OS-specific method to enumerate all processes that exist. There is no POSIX-standard C API for doing so.
2. For every process ID, send the signal `0` (dummy signal used for permission checks only). If you get zero, you're allowed to kill that process; if you get -EPERM, you're not.

Note that doing this in order to subsequently kill all those processes is a waste of time, because you can just send the actual signal as soon as you know the PID. (Not to mention that it depends on non-POSIX features for process enumeration.)